# How to scrape items having same class and id

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrape

I want to scrape person name, location and phone no but all thses have same class and no id.Here is the link of that web page: https://hipages.com.au/connect/emcoelectricalservices Please guide me. than you!

here is mo code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    if not response.ok:
        print('server responded:', response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    return soup

def get_detail_data(soup):

    try:
        title = (soup.find('h1', class_="sc-AykKI",id=False).text)
    except:
        title = 'Empty Title'
    print(title)

    try:
        contact_person = (soup.find('span', class_="kBpGee",id=False).text)
    except:
        contact_person = 'Empty Person'
    print(contact_person)

    try:
        location = (soup.find('span', class_="kBpGee",id=False).text)
    except:
        location = 'Empty location'
    print(location)



def main():
    #get data of detail page
    url = "https://hipages.com.au/connect/emcoelectricalservices"
    #get_page(url)
    get_detail_data(get_page(url))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the below works:-

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Mar  4 09:52:13 2020

@author: prakh
"""

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    if not response.ok:
        print('server responded:', response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    return soup


def get_detail_data(soup):
    titles = []
    persons = []
    locations = []

    try:
        titles.append(soup.find('h1', class_="sc-AykKI",id=False).text)
    except:
        titles.append('Empty Title')

    try:
        persons.append(soup.findAll('span', class_="Contact__Item-sc-1giw2l4-2 kBpGee",id=False)[1].text)
    except:
        persons.append('Empty Person')

    try:
        locations.append(soup.findAll('span', class_="Contact__Item-sc-1giw2l4-2 kBpGee",id=False)[2].text)

    except:
        locations.append('Empty location')   
    final_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Title': titles,
     'contact_person': persons,
     'location': locations
    })
    print(final_df)

def main():
    #get data of detail page
    url = "https://hipages.com.au/connect/emcoelectricalservices"
    #get_page(url)
    get_detail_data(get_page(url))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi thanks! But it is showing **** for phone no. Is it possible to show phone number

Comment: You need to use selenium for that. The webpage requires the phone number element to be clicked to make it visible. We cannot do it with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Could you please write small code for selenium? please sir help me!

Comment: @MuhammadAkram i suggest you open a separate question for that. Also please try and show research from your end. Stackoverflow is not a platform to hand out your assignments or work directly. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sir one more thing please. Sir when I run this code for multiple records using for loop and if there are some data missing like contact_person then as you use index no[1] and [2] for person variable location will be extracted. Could you please fix this issue

Comment: @MuhammadAkram i have modified the code to handle missing values.
If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left handside in my answer. And feel free to up vote the answer.